# Column name must be either a string or an array yii

Tags: php, yii

i got some stuck when accessing a yii's web application. I have configured as the same as the owner's setting, but while i tried to access, i got an error "Column must be either a string or an array". How could i solve it? Thanks in advance..

Comment: I had the id column as INDEX instead of PRIMARY, changed to PRIMARY and problem solved.

Comment: Haha can't believe this. Found my own comment after 5 years. :D

Answer (score 6):

When reporting error messages, it helps to have the precise error message. The actual error message is: "Column **name** must be either a string or an array". With an exact string you can search the framework files to find where it is mentioned.

Looks like some method somewhere is passing an invalid column name to `createInCondition` method of CDbCommandBuilder.

See line 722: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/db/schema/CDbCommandBuilder.php

Looking at a couple instances where that method is called, I would guess that you have a database table without a primary key somewhere. That is one possible explanation for the problem. Other explanations will require a lot more details on your part.

Provide the stack trace that the error page provides you with when in debug mode along with your table schema.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Willem. I tried your suggestion to define the model's primary key, but it didn't work. then i've tried this solution [link]http://www.tipstank.com/2010/06/14/declare-single-composite-primary-key-yii-activerecord/ but the error message turn into 'Trying to get property of non-object'. Could you suggest another help? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This happens when you don't have a primary key in your table and you try to do an update. I got this problem because I had a composite primary key in my table. I was being handled well on all operations until I wanted to update a model.

Just add an int primary key, call it 'id' to your table with auto increment. It should do the trick.

Be sure to disable schema caching (if you're using that) before you test this. The change wont take effect until your schema cache expires.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you do not have `primary key` in your table. If you use the method $model->save() to save or use method $model->update() ($model is CActiveRecord instance), you will get this error.

Because the method update in CActiveRecord using Primary key to update (Read more [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L1115)
)

Source Code: framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#1115

```
if($this->_pk===null)
        $this->_pk=$this->getPrimaryKey();
$this->updateByPk($this->getOldPrimaryKey(),$this->getAttributes($attributes));
$this->_pk=$this->getPrimaryKey();
```

You can use method `updateAll()` instead of `update()` or `updateByPk()`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look this link

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/3887-cdbexception-column-name-must-be-either-a-string-or-an-array/

It seems your table doesn't have a `primary key` or the primary key doesn't well restored which usually caused by corrupt back up file.

Answer (score 0):

If you forgot add return value you will have error you showed. Simple example, your model with such method will return error on PK

```
...

public function relations()
{
}

...
```

Your have to add return value.

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function relations()
{
    return array();
}
```

If you are not using such methods you should delete them, or add 'default return values'. Otherwise it gives errors the same as it was primary key or other DB issues (because model read invalid data and didn't all things it should).