# yii1 update DB query giving error

Tags: php, yii

I want to update one field in my db. I have the below query, but I am getting error in this.

```
           $list = Test::model()->find(array(
                    'select'=>'name',
                    'condition'=>'id=:id AND name=:name AND provider="fb"',
                    'params'=>array(
                        ':id'=>Yii::app()->user->id,
                        ':name'=> $name,
                        ),
            ));

            $list->name = $user_name[$k]['name'];
            if($list->save())
                {
                  echo "done";exit;
            }
            else
            {
                $error = $list->getErrors();
                var_dump($error);exit;
            }
```

Error:
    `'Column name must be either a string or an array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you don't have a primary key in your table and you try to save some data in table. check if you have set primary key and it set properly. [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271257/column-name-must-be-either-a-string-or-an-array-yii)

Comment: based on my requirement, I do not need primary key in this table

Comment: then checkout [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12361-yet-model-with-no-primary-key/)